# transfer file from filezilla to local path C:\ using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have `.txt`  files in FileZilla server. I need to transfer files from FileZilla server to Local Path `C:\`
Below is the code i am running in job schedule,

```
prompt
lcd C:\
open sftp.getixhealth.com 20**strong text**2
abcd
xyz
bin
cd /In
mput *.txt
Quit
```

Comment: these are not filezilla commands.. have you tried `fzsftp.exe --help`

Comment: may i know the code how to transfer files from FileZilla to Local path C:\ using batch files

Comment: I need to create batch file so that i can transfer FileZilla server file path \In to my local path C:\..Do you have code for it?